# External monitors

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have installed Kubuntu 20.04, on a Huawei Matebook 13, with an NVIDIA GeForce MX250 graphics adapter. My goal is to connect 2 additional external monitors using the USB-C docking station Sandberg, which supports extending and mirror mode.

Ubuntu only recognizes one external monitor and, when I turn both on, I have the same image on both external screens. I would like to expand the desktop to use all 3 screens, one built-in and 2 external.

This is a screenshot of my display configuration:

[image: screenshot of my display configuration]

This is the output of `xrandr`:

[image: output of xrandr]

This is my monitor setup:

[image: my monitor setup]

How can I do this?

Comment: Silly question, but *which side of the notebook* is the adapter plugged in to? The right side USB-C port supports the full data-transfer speed and DisplayPort, whereas the USB-C port on the left is designed for power and *limited* data transfer 

Comment: it is on the right side. One more thing, on windows it is working fine, and after system update, same problem. Not sure why?

Comment: It looks nothing like Ubuntu.

Comment: KDE desktop is installed